Angular component with content projection causes incorrect service injection
I have an Angular directive (LevelDirective) designed to determine its level based on its parent's level (i.e. if parent has level 1 => I should have level 2). It uses a standalone LevelService to store the level. The directive works as expected until I introduce content projection with a custom component (UsingLevelComponent).
The directive and its service that is created on every directive instance:
@Injectable()
export class LevelService {
    public level = signal(1);
    public id = new Guid().toString(); // custom util, creates a unique identifier
}

@Directive({
    selector: "[myLevel]",
    standalone: true,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: LevelService,
            useFactory: (self: LevelDirective): LevelService => {
                const service = new LevelService();

                if (!self) {
                    return service;
                }

                service.level.set(self.level());
                return service;
            },
            deps: [LevelDirective],
        },
    ],
})
export class LevelDirective {
    private readonly parentService = inject(LevelService, { skipSelf: true, optional: true });

    public readonly level = computed<number>((): number => {
        if (!this.parentService) {
            return 1;
        }

        return this.parentService.level() + 1;
    });

    @HostBinding("class")
    public get hostClasses(): string {
        return `level-${this.level()} service-id-${this.parentService?.id}`;
    }
}

The component that just prints the current level:
@Component({
    selector: "level-aware",
    template: `
        <p>Current level: {{ levelService?.level() ?? "undefined" }}</p>
    `,
})
export class LevelAwareComponent {
    constructor(private levelService: LevelService) {}
}

The component that uses myLevel and ng-content
@Component({
    selector: "using-level",
    template: `
        <div myLevel>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class UsingLevelComponent {}

The problem
When I am using myLevel in the same template with the level-aware component, everything works as expected.
<div myLevel>
    <div myLevel>
        <level-aware></level-aware>
    </div>
</div>

Output:
Current level: 2

If I am to introduce the component that uses content projection, I get unexpected behaviour:
<div myLevel>
    <div myLevel>
        <using-level>
            <level-aware></level-aware>
        </using-level>
    </div>
</div>

Output:
Current level: 2

The output should be Current level: 3 since my level-aware component "lives" under 3 myLevel instance – 2 declared in the template and 1 within using-level.
It gets even weirder if introduce another using-level component and look at the rendered markup. The directive instances that follow the one declared in using-level, start to point to the same instance of the service.
<div myLevel>
    <div myLevel>
        <using-level>
            <using-level>
                <level-aware></level-aware>
            </using-level>
        </using-level>
    </div>
</div>

Output:
Current level: 2

HTML:
        <div mylevel class="level-1 service-id-undefined">
            <div mylevel class="level-2 service-id-656cac79-2e53-6915-edb8-093bcaefa20c">
                <using-level>
                    <div mylevel class="level-3 service-id-fa6f8ba9-7ce2-6e5d-2b98-7506cf203a9c">
                        <using-level>
                            <div mylevel class="level-3 service-id-fa6f8ba9-7ce2-6e5d-2b98-7506cf203a9c">
                                <level-aware><p>Current level: 2</p></level-aware>
                            </div>
                        </using-level>
                    </div>
                </using-level>
            </div>
        </div>

Question
What's causing this discrepancy between the DOM structure and the injected service when using content projection? How can I ensure the correct LevelService instance is used within the projected content?
The service can be completely omited – instead of setting the level signal in the service, LevelDirective can be injected in the same manner and its level computed signal can be accessed directly. However, the outcome is the same.
I also tried turning my LevelDirective into a component, still yields the same unexpected behaviour.
// LevelDirective
public readonly parent = inject(LevelDirective, { skipSelf: true, optional: true }); //instead of parentService

// LevelAwareComponent
public readonly levelDirective = inject(LevelDirective, { optional: true }); //instead of levelService

Repro
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17-starter-project-gdzqrs?file=src%2Fmain.ts

When you use content projection, the content you use, is actually initialized the same place you define it, so its working fine technically.

Do you mean that projected content is not inserted in using-layer component but is rather its sibling?
Then I'd assume that onAfterViewInit I could "re-inject" the correct service. Do you think I can work around it?

All are initialized at the same level, so the count stays the same, could you also share a stackblitz where the issue happens for better checking, also why you want to do this, maybe there is a better way with less complexity?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17-starter-project-gdzqrs?file=src%2Fmain.ts

My goal is to create a directive (myLevel) that automatically calculates its own level based on its parent's level. If a parent directive has level 3, its direct child should have level 4, and so on. The key take is that the directive should report its level within the component hierarchy, even when content projection is used. For that I use the LayerService, whereas the LayerAwareComponent wants to know at what level it sits within the DOM hierarchy.

This is my version of the solution. We can basically access the ElementRef and check if there are child nodes, if there are child nodes, then it's from content projection, so we increment by 2. This seems to solve the issue.
...
export class LevelDirective {
  elementRef = inject(ElementRef);
  private readonly parentService = inject(LevelService, {
    skipSelf: true,
    optional: true,
  });

  public readonly level = computed<number>((): number => {
    if (!this.parentService) {
      return 1;
    }
    return this.elementRef.nativeElement.childNodes.length
      ? this.parentService.getLevel() + 2
      : this.parentService.getLevel() + 1;
  });

  @HostBinding('class')
  public get hostClasses(): string {
    return `level-${this.level()} service-${this.parentService?.id}`;
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

This is not a maintainable solution.
First, multiple components/HTML elements can separate the directive declaration. Therefore nativeElement.childNodes.length won't work.
Second, I can't know how many declarations of the myLevel there'll be in my app, so I can't conditionally increment by 1,2,3, etc.
Thanks for suggesting a different approach though.

@AlexandruTatarciuc this is the inherent behaviour of content projection, you can also pass in a flag to the directive to inform if it's content projection

@AlexandruTatarciuc as for the scenario you mentioned, you need to add a wrapper div and take a content child of that and then check the child nodes
